# How can I deduce that a postfix declarator operator like '[]' binds tigther than a prefix one like '*' using §8.3.1 and §8.3.4?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, language-lawyer

Consider the expression `new (int(*[x]));` in the example in §8.2/3:

```
#include <cstddef>
char *p;
void *operator new(std::size_t, int);
void foo() {
    const int x = 63;
    new (int(*p)) int; // new-placement expression
    new (int(*[x])); // new type-id
}
```

I know that this expression allocates an array of 63 pointers to `int` in the free store. From §8.3/6 we can eliminate the parentheses in `int(*[x])`, obtaining the expression `new (int*[x]);`. But I'm having a problem establishing that the type `int*[x]` is an array of 63 pointers to `int` and not a pointer to an array of 63 `int` using paragraphs §8.3.1 and §8.3.4.

Comment: By knowing the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg AFAIK the Standard doesn't have an operator precedence table. You have to deduce it from the paragraphs in the Standard.

Comment: And if you read the linked reference, you will see this: "The standard itself doesn't specify precedence levels. They are derived from the grammar." But instead of knowing the grammar it's easier to know a table derived from the grammar, or at least easier to go to the reference to see the table than go to the specification and read the grammar every time.

Comment: The precedence is implicit in **8/4**, in the interplay between *ptr-declarator* and *noptr-declarator*. Essentially, a *ptr-operator* (of which a star `*` is one) may only appear at the top level, or else enclosed in parentheses. Thus, `*id[x]` cannot be parsed as `*id` followed by `[x]` (the declarator before square brackets must be a *noptr-declarator*), but only as `*` followed by `id[x]` - which would then match the pattern of **8.3.1 Pointers** rather than **8.3.4 Arrays**

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Brilliant. Please submit the text above as an answer, so that I can close the thread. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precedence is implicit in the syntax diagram at **8/4**, in the interplay between *ptr-declarator* and *noptr-declarator*. According to the syntax, `*id[x]` cannot be parsed as `*id` followed by `[x]` (the declarator before square brackets must be a *noptr-declarator*), but only as `*` followed by `id[x]`. This reading then matches the pattern of **8.3.1 Pointers** rather than that of **8.3.4 Arrays**.